# Memory problems

Tags: c++, pointers

I have some singleton class (please, don't speak about singleton usage).

```
class InputSystem : boost::serialization::singleton<InputSystem>
{
private:
   boost::shared_ptr<sf::Window> mInputWindow;
public:
   InputSystem()
   {
      mInputWindow = boost::shared_ptr<sf::Window>( new sf::Window(someARgs) );
      someMethod();
   }

   void someMethod()
   {
      mInputWindow->...() // Calling some methods of sf::Window class
      // Everything  is fine here
   }

   const sf::Input &Handle() const
   {
      return mInputWindow.get()->GetInput();
   }
};

void main()
{
   InputSystem::get_mutable_instance().Handle(); // Here is all members of InputSystem have invalid addresses in memory (0x000)
}
```

What's wrong could be there?

Comment: It's impossible to answer without `singleton::get_mutable_instance()` definition.

Comment: So, what's your `singleton<>` class template like? (And how can everything be fine at `someMethod()` when you don't ever call it in the example code?) Incomplete samples do not great questions make.

Comment: @Klaim That is singleton from boost serialization

Comment: @pontus-gagge my post is updated

Comment: @Ockonal: AFAIK, Boost has no singleton class you're intended to use, so you might get bad results when using those singletons. (Not that you should use one anyway...\*duck\*).

Comment: @gman http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/serialization/doc/singleton.html that is =)

Comment: @Ockonal: Well I'll be damned, it does seem intended to be used. :]

Comment: @GMan: several singleton classes have appeared in boost over the years, only to disappear a couple of versions later when the author realised how bad an idea they are. @Ockonal: regardless of whether singletons are a good idea or not, I wouldn't rely on this class existing in future versions of boost.

Comment: Did you figure out your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here is all members of InputSystem have invalid addresses in memory (`0x000`)

Either `someMethod()` is zeroing your class data, or you have misdiagnosed the issue.

Change your main function to this:

```
InputSystem& inputSystem = InputSystem::get_mutable_instance();
inputSystem.Handle();
```

This puts the creation of the singleton and the first attempt to use it onto separate lines.  Fire up your debugger and step through the code looking for the exact point that your singleton's data is corrupted.

Comment: At the point of getting instance of the class, all data are destroyed.

Comment: @Ockonal: Is your constructor ever called?

Comment: @gunslinger47 yeah, debugger shows me that `someMethod()` calls.

Comment: Is `mInputWindow` null when `someMethod()` is called?

Comment: @gunslinger47 nope, everything is fine there

Comment: Is `mInputWindow` null at the end of `someMethod()`? X-D

Comment: @Ock: So when _does_ it turn null, then?

Comment: When calling `InputSystem::get_mutable_instance();` in main function.